# How to merge JSON nested value and adding separators using python 2.7

Tags: python, json

The original JSON data is :

{'aaData':['address':"805 Second Avenue", 'location': "New York, NY", 'zip': "10022"]}.

How can I merge these value and return a single object which may look like this:

{'aaData':['XXX': "805 Second Avenue, New York, NY 10022"]}?

Comment: that's not a json object

Comment: And even if you turn it into a JSON object by changing the parentheses into braces, where does the `'XXX'` come from?